# How to join these tables MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

How to join these 3 tables here.

[image]

I want to get the product NAME.

```
SELECT order_detail.productid 
FROM order_detail
INNER JOIN orders 
  ON orders.id_order = order_detail.orderid
INNER JOIN products 
 ON orders.id_order=products.id_product
```

The sql query returns zero column.. what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are joining your `orders.id_order=products.id_product` but it seems like you need to join `order_detail.productid=products.id_product`. So I'd suggest changing your query to:

```
SELECT 
   od.productid,
   p.name_product  -- added name column
FROM order_detail od
INNER JOIN orders o
  ON o.id_order = od.orderid
INNER JOIN products p
 ON od.productid=p.id_product
```

You'll notice that I added some table aliases to make the code a bit more concise. Also if you don't need to use the `orders` table in your final result, then you could drop joining to it:

```
SELECT 
   od.productid,
   p.name_product
FROM order_detail od
INNER JOIN products p
 ON od.productid=p.id_product
```

Comment: are you sure about this? because i getting result, but not the right one

Comment: @GoranAhibit What result are you getting? And what is the desired result that you want?  You might need to edit your question to include some sample data and the final desired result.

Comment: @GoranAhibit: Can you please share the expected output and the output that you're getting? In any case, joining `int` with `varchar` without casting (as per your diagram) is never a good idea and is bound to give irrational outputs.

Comment: @GoranAhibit And what are you expecting as the final result?

Comment: i have to print out the product name

Comment: where the delivered column is undelivered, but thats a simple where statement

Comment: @GoranAhibit I'm not sure I'm following, the query produces the product name - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9b85/2

Comment: yes, its working! thank you for your help. I managed now to work only with one query in my php application. thank you! :)